# Unable to compile when augmenting OktaAuthService typescript module

Tags: angular, typescript, okta, module-augmentation

Scenario:

My project is using the latest version of @okta/okta-angular. It exports the class 'OktaAuthService'. I would like to use module augmentation to add a method to it

What I've tried

```
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';

declare module '@okta/okta-angular' {
  interface OktaAuthService {
    getUserRole(): Promise<RoleEnum>;
  } 
}

OktaAuthService.prototype.getUserRole = function (): Promise<Role> {
  return OktaAuthService.prototype.getUser().then(userClaims => {
   //pseudo code
   if user has claim 
     return Role;
   //
  });
}
```

According to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation this should work, however

- the interface appears to be ghosting the import (TS2693 'OktaAuthService' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here (where I set the getUserRole function)
- If I remove the new function, but leave the module, compilation fails everywhere I import from "@okta/okta-angular"

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use interface inheritance, example:

```
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';


interface OktaAuthServiceCustom extends OktaAuthService {
    getUserRole(): Promise<RoleEnum>;
} 


OktaAuthService.prototype.getUserRole = function (): Promise<Role> {
  return (OktaAuthService as OktaAuthServiceCustom).prototype.getUser().then(userClaims => {
   //pseudo code
   if user has claim 
     return Role;
   //
  });
}
```

Comment: Taking the example as a working example I have some challenges (this is the first time I've tried this sort of thing)

This gives me compile time warnings about 
- getUserRole does not exist on type OktaAuthService
- OktaAuthService and OktaAuthServiceCustom don't overlap enough for the cast
- getUserRole isn't a member of OktaAuthService.prototype

Sorry, can you expand a little more?

Comment: So, try:

interface OktaAuthServiceCustom extends OktaAuthService {
    prototype: {
        getUserRole(): Promise<RoleEnum>;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being as follows

```
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import { RoleEnum } from '../model/Enums';


declare module '@okta/okta-angular/src/okta/services/okta.service' {
  interface OktaAuthService {
    getUserRole(): Promise<RoleEnum>;
  } 
}

OktaAuthService.prototype.getUserRole = function (): Promise<RoleEnum> {
  return this.getUser().then(userClaims => {
});
}
```